# Rails - Controller Object Scope vs Controller Function Scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, variables, model-view-controller

I have seen local variables as well as object variables being used in Rails controller actions. An example of both is given below:

```
# Local variable
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def some_action
    local_variable = Model.find(<some-condition>).delete
  end
end

# Object variable
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def some_action
    @object_variable = Model.find(<some-condition>).delete
  end
end
```

I want to know what is the difference between both of them and the scenarios that they are both suited to be used in.

Comment: One difference would be you can't use `local_varaibles` defined in controller in views but you can use `object_variables`.

Comment: btw you should really not use `delete`

Comment: Right use `.destroy` instead of `.delete`. `delete` does not call any callbacks on the the model such as cascading destroys (destroy child records when parent is deleted) or any cleanup.

Answer (score 4):

Rails exports the controller's instance variables into what is called the view context:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def new 
    @user = User.new
  end
end
```

---

```
# the view gets any @ variables from the controller.
# views/users/new.html.haml
= form_for(@user) do
```

Rails also offers another mechanism called locals as well:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def new 
    render :new, locals: { user: User.new }
  end
end
```

---

```
# locals are lexical variables in the view context.
# views/users/new.html.haml
= form_for(user) do
```

Which exports a local variable to the view context.

### So when do you use what?

Use lexical (local) variables (some_variable) for anything you do not want to implicitly export to the view. Use the locals option when rendering when you need to pass data between views and partials or things that are not quite part of the "public api" of your controller.

Use instance variables (@foo) only for important exports from your controller and treat them as part of a public API. Make sure you test them:

```
describe UserController do
  describe "#new" do
    before { get :new }
    it "assigns as new user as @user" do
      expect(assigns(:user)).to be_a_new_record
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In your provided code, `local_variable` would only be available to the current method in the controller. Your `@object_variable` would be available to the method, but also to the view (to be accesses directly as `@object_variable`)

Therefore, you should reserve using `@object_variable` for only when you want to use the variable in your views.